# keras load model error trying to load a weight file containing 17 layers into a model with 0 layers

Tags: python, model, keras, deep-learning

I am currently working on vgg16 model with keras.
I fine tune vgg model with some of my layer.
After fitting my model (training), I save my model with `model.save('name.h5')`.
It can be saved without problem. 
However, when I try to reload the model with `load_model` function, it shows the error:

> You are trying to load a weight file containing 17 layers into a model
>   with 0 layers

Did anyone meet this problem before?
My keras verion is 2.2.

Here is part of my code ...

```
from keras.models import load_model
vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224,224,3))    
global model_2
model_2 = Sequential()
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    model_2.add(layer)
for layer in model_2.layers:
    layer.trainable= False
model_2.add(Flatten())
model_2.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_2.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model_2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_2.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=32,epochs=30,verbose=2)
model_2.save('name.h5')
del model_2
model_2 = load_model('name.h5')
```

Actually I do not delete the model and then `load_model` immediately, 
just for showing my problem.

Comment: I could run your code on my machine without any problems (without the fitting part, of course). It is a strange error...are you sure this is the exact code you use? Do you use Keras on Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is related with the *input_shape* parameter of the first layer. I had this problem with a wrapper layer (Bidirectional) which did not have an input_shape parameter set. In code:

```
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=units, input_shape=(None, feature_size)), merge_mode='concat'))
```

did not work for loading my old model because the input_shape is only defined for the LSTM layer not the outer one. Instead

```
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=units), input_shape=(None, feature_size), merge_mode='concat'))
```

worked because the wrapper Birectional layer now has an input_shape parameter. Maybe you should check if the VGG net input_shape parameter is set or not or you should add a single *input_layer* to your model with the correct *input_shape* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 6 hours looking around for a solution.. to apply me trained model.
finally i tried VGG16 as model and using h5 weights i´ve trained on my own and Great!

```
weights_model='C:/Anaconda/weightsnew2.h5'  # my already trained weights .h5
vgg=applications.vgg16.VGG16()
cnn=Sequential()
for capa in vgg.layers:
   cnn.add(capa)
cnn.layers.pop()
for layer in cnn.layers:
   layer.trainable=False
cnn.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))  

cnn.load_weights(weights_model)

def predict(file):
   x = load_img(file, target_size=(longitud, altura)) 
   x = img_to_array(x)                            
   x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
   array = cnn.predict(x)     
   result = array[0]
   respuesta = np.argmax(result) 
   if respuesta == 0:
      print("Gato")
   elif respuesta == 1:
      print("Perro")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code solves the problem the person asking has?

Comment: Yes I´ve used to face same error "keras load model error trying to load a weight file containing 17 layers into a model with 0 layers" because looks it is about a kind of 2bug" in Load_model function from Keras. But if instead of load_model="file" you defie the model , and then Load weights. It works. the problem occurs just when you try to load_model.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still wondering about this error:

I had the same Problem and spent days figuring out, whats causing it. I have a copy of my whole code and dataset on another system on which it worked. I noticed that it is something about the training, because without training my model, saving and loading was no problem.
The only difference between my systems was, that I was using tensorflow-gpu on my main system and for this reason, the tensorflow base version was a little bit lower (1.14.0 instead of 2.2.0). So all I had to do was using

```
model.fit_generator()
```

instead of

```
model.fit()
```

before saving it. And it works