# How to repair a saved model to avoid `ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 3 layers into a model with 0 layers.`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I know this questions has already been asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913225/keras-load-model-error-trying-to-load-a-weight-file-containing-17-layers-into-a) for example), but no answer was provided.
Here is my small model:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

IMGSIZE = 128

model = Sequential()

# Input/Encoder
model.add(Dense(IMGSIZE, activation='relu'))
# Code layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
#Decoder
model.add(Dense(IMGSIZE, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
history = model.fit(X, X, batch_size=50, epochs=1, verbose=1)

model.save("autoencodermodel.h5")
```

Then I trained the model **for days, with a huge number of epochs, and I don't want to do it again.**
So today, after a reboot (model isn't anymore in the memory), I tried this :

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("autoencodermodel.h5")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-1393db34e61d> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
----> 2 model = load_model("autoencodermodel.h5")

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    262 
    263         # set weights
--> 264         load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)
    265 
    266         if compile:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers, reshape)
    899                          'containing ' + str(len(layer_names)) +
    900                          ' layers into a model with ' +
--> 901                          str(len(filtered_layers)) + ' layers.')
    902 
    903     # We batch weight value assignments in a single backend call

ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 3 layers into a model with 0 layers.
```

So now, I can do it again but with **specifying the input shape**. But I don't want and I don't have time to train it again.
I save and (try to) load the model on the same computer, with the same version of Keras using tensorflow backend.

## Is there a way to hack the .h5 file to make the load_model function work ?

Next time, I'll use an `Input` layer to avoid this problem (bug ?).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  A saved model is mostly a list of weights that correspond to every detail of the original model topology.  It appears that you want to load that file into a different model topology.

Comment: I did save the model, not only the weights.
I'd like to get back the whole model, ie the topology/architecture of the layers with their associated weights

Comment: Ah -- the problem is simply how to reload a Keras model.  This isn't a matter of hacking the file.

Comment: As far as I can see, you've followed the [proper protocol](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I don't understand why it doesn't work. It seems like a bug, and to make it work we should hard write the input shape in the model. But I didn't do it, so that's why I speak about "hacking the file" to transform it in a model with an `Input` layer.